# Joomla redirects Application url under IIS

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, mod-rewrite, joomla

I've installed php support on my IIS7 via FastCGI. Under IIS I've created a new website that host Joomla. Uploaded my site and it works fine.

Now I wanted to add another application under that website so that when someone goes to my url http://www.mysite.com/application_name he will get to the site hosted under that url.

What ends up happening is that on Chrome and Firefox I see the Application site, but on IE it points me to the root of the site (http://www.mysite.com/application_name points me to http://www.mysite.com/).

I've played around with .htaaccess file but had no luck. I even removed it entirely but it still does that and even when removed the entire joomla site keeps on working.

What configuration am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.htaccess works only under Apache servers, it doesn't work on IIS. You should work on the web.config file.